# Why did we create two of pq here?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, a-star

This line below belongs to a C++ code of A star algorithm and it's created two priority queues here. What does these two mean?.

```
 static priority_queue<node> pq[2]; // list of open (not-yet-tried) nodes
```

The snippet that contains this line:

```
// A-star algorithm.
// The route returned is a string of direction digits.
string pathFind( const int & xStart, const int & yStart, 
                 const int & xFinish, const int & yFinish )
{
    static priority_queue<node> pq[2]; // list of open (not-yet-tried) nodes
    static int pqi; // pq index
    static node* n0;
    static node* m0;
    static int i, j, x, y, xdx, ydy;
    static char c;
    pqi=0;
```

Here I post below the full code for review:

```
// Astar.cpp
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*
// Compiler: Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2
// FB - 201012256
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int n=60; // horizontal size of the map
const int m=60; // vertical size size of the map
static int map[n][m];
static int closed_nodes_map[n][m]; // map of closed (tried-out) nodes
static int open_nodes_map[n][m]; // map of open (not-yet-tried) nodes
static int dir_map[n][m]; // map of directions
const int dir=8; // number of possible directions to go at any position
// if dir==4
//static int dx[dir]={1, 0, -1, 0};
//static int dy[dir]={0, 1, 0, -1};
// if dir==8
static int dx[dir]={1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1};
static int dy[dir]={0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1};

class node
{
    // current position
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
    // total distance already travelled to reach the node
    int level;
    // priority=level+remaining distance estimate
    int priority;  // smaller: higher priority

    public:
        node(int xp, int yp, int d, int p) 
            {xPos=xp; yPos=yp; level=d; priority=p;}

        int getxPos() const {return xPos;}
        int getyPos() const {return yPos;}
        int getLevel() const {return level;}
        int getPriority() const {return priority;}

        void updatePriority(const int & xDest, const int & yDest)
        {
             priority=level+estimate(xDest, yDest)*10; //A*
        }

        // give better priority to going strait instead of diagonally
        void nextLevel(const int & i) // i: direction
        {
             level+=(dir==8?(i%2==0?10:14):10);
        }

        // Estimation function for the remaining distance to the goal.
        const int & estimate(const int & xDest, const int & yDest) const
        {
            static int xd, yd, d;
            xd=xDest-xPos;
            yd=yDest-yPos;         

            // Euclidian Distance
            d=static_cast<int>(sqrt(xd*xd+yd*yd));

            // Manhattan distance
            //d=abs(xd)+abs(yd);

            // Chebyshev distance
            //d=max(abs(xd), abs(yd));

            return(d);
        }
};

// Determine priority (in the priority queue)
bool operator<(const node & a, const node & b)
{
  return a.getPriority() > b.getPriority();
}

// A-star algorithm.
// The route returned is a string of direction digits.
string pathFind( const int & xStart, const int & yStart, 
                 const int & xFinish, const int & yFinish )
{
    static priority_queue<node> pq[2]; // list of open (not-yet-tried) nodes
    static int pqi; // pq index
    static node* n0;
    static node* m0;
    static int i, j, x, y, xdx, ydy;
    static char c;
    pqi=0;

    // reset the node maps
    for(y=0;y<m;y++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<n;x++)
        {
            closed_nodes_map[x][y]=0;
            open_nodes_map[x][y]=0;
        }
    }

    // create the start node and push into list of open nodes
    n0=new node(xStart, yStart, 0, 0);
    n0->updatePriority(xFinish, yFinish);
    pq[pqi].push(*n0);
    open_nodes_map[x][y]=n0->getPriority(); // mark it on the open nodes map

    // A* search
    while(!pq[pqi].empty())
    {
        // get the current node w/ the highest priority
        // from the list of open nodes
        n0=new node( pq[pqi].top().getxPos(), pq[pqi].top().getyPos(), 
                     pq[pqi].top().getLevel(), pq[pqi].top().getPriority());

        x=n0->getxPos(); y=n0->getyPos();

        pq[pqi].pop(); // remove the node from the open list
        open_nodes_map[x][y]=0;
        // mark it on the closed nodes map
        closed_nodes_map[x][y]=1;

        // quit searching when the goal state is reached
        //if((*n0).estimate(xFinish, yFinish) == 0)
        if(x==xFinish && y==yFinish) 
        {
            // generate the path from finish to start
            // by following the directions
            string path="";
            while(!(x==xStart && y==yStart))
            {
                j=dir_map[x][y];
                c='0'+(j+dir/2)%dir;
                path=c+path;
                x+=dx[j];
                y+=dy[j];
            }

            // garbage collection
            delete n0;
            // empty the leftover nodes
            while(!pq[pqi].empty()) pq[pqi].pop();           
            return path;
        }

        // generate moves (child nodes) in all possible directions
        for(i=0;i<dir;i++)
        {
            xdx=x+dx[i]; ydy=y+dy[i];

            if(!(xdx<0 || xdx>n-1 || ydy<0 || ydy>m-1 || map[xdx][ydy]==1 
                || closed_nodes_map[xdx][ydy]==1))
            {
                // generate a child node
                m0=new node( xdx, ydy, n0->getLevel(), 
                             n0->getPriority());
                m0->nextLevel(i);
                m0->updatePriority(xFinish, yFinish);

                // if it is not in the open list then add into that
                if(open_nodes_map[xdx][ydy]==0)
                {
                    open_nodes_map[xdx][ydy]=m0->getPriority();
                    pq[pqi].push(*m0);
                    // mark its parent node direction
                    dir_map[xdx][ydy]=(i+dir/2)%dir;
                }
                else if(open_nodes_map[xdx][ydy]>m0->getPriority())
                {
                    // update the priority info
                    open_nodes_map[xdx][ydy]=m0->getPriority();
                    // update the parent direction info
                    dir_map[xdx][ydy]=(i+dir/2)%dir;

                    // replace the node
                    // by emptying one pq to the other one
                    // except the node to be replaced will be ignored
                    // and the new node will be pushed in instead
                    while(!(pq[pqi].top().getxPos()==xdx && 
                           pq[pqi].top().getyPos()==ydy))
                    {                
                        pq[1-pqi].push(pq[pqi].top());
                        pq[pqi].pop();       
                    }
                    pq[pqi].pop(); // remove the wanted node

                    // empty the larger size pq to the smaller one
                    if(pq[pqi].size()>pq[1-pqi].size()) pqi=1-pqi;
                    while(!pq[pqi].empty())
                    {                
                        pq[1-pqi].push(pq[pqi].top());
                        pq[pqi].pop();       
                    }
                    pqi=1-pqi;
                    pq[pqi].push(*m0); // add the better node instead
                }
                else delete m0; // garbage collection
            }
        }
        delete n0; // garbage collection
    }
    return ""; // no route found
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    // create empty map
    for(int y=0;y<m;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<n;x++) map[x][y]=0;
    }

    // fillout the map matrix with a '+' pattern
    for(int x=n/8;x<n*7/8;x++)
    {
        map[x][m/2]=1;
    }
    for(int y=m/8;y<m*7/8;y++)
    {
        map[n/2][y]=1;
    }

    // randomly select start and finish locations
    int xA, yA, xB, yB;
    switch(rand()%8)
    {
        case 0: xA=0;yA=0;xB=n-1;yB=m-1; break;
        case 1: xA=0;yA=m-1;xB=n-1;yB=0; break;
        case 2: xA=n/2-1;yA=m/2-1;xB=n/2+1;yB=m/2+1; break;
        case 3: xA=n/2-1;yA=m/2+1;xB=n/2+1;yB=m/2-1; break;
        case 4: xA=n/2-1;yA=0;xB=n/2+1;yB=m-1; break;
        case 5: xA=n/2+1;yA=m-1;xB=n/2-1;yB=0; break;
        case 6: xA=0;yA=m/2-1;xB=n-1;yB=m/2+1; break;
        case 7: xA=n-1;yA=m/2+1;xB=0;yB=m/2-1; break;
    }

    cout<<"Map Size (X,Y): "<<n<<","<<m<<endl;
    cout<<"Start: "<<xA<<","<<yA<<endl;
    cout<<"Finish: "<<xB<<","<<yB<<endl;
    // get the route
    clock_t start = clock();
    string route=pathFind(xA, yA, xB, yB);
    if(route=="") cout<<"An empty route generated!"<<endl;
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_elapsed = double(end - start);
    cout<<"Time to calculate the route (ms): "<<time_elapsed<<endl;
    cout<<"Route:"<<endl;
    cout<<route<<endl<<endl;

    // follow the route on the map and display it 
    if(route.length()>0)
    {
        int j; char c;
        int x=xA;
        int y=yA;
        map[x][y]=2;
        for(int i=0;i<route.length();i++)
        {
            c =route.at(i);
            j=atoi(&c); 
            x=x+dx[j];
            y=y+dy[j];
            map[x][y]=3;
        }
        map[x][y]=4;

        // display the map with the route
        for(int y=0;y<m;y++)
        {
            for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
                if(map[x][y]==0)
                    cout<<".";
                else if(map[x][y]==1)
                    cout<<"O"; //obstacle
                else if(map[x][y]==2)
                    cout<<"S"; //start
                else if(map[x][y]==3)
                    cout<<"R"; //route
                else if(map[x][y]==4)
                    cout<<"F"; //finish
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    getchar(); // wait for a (Enter) keypress  
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: A very brief search through the shown code shows `pqi` is being used as a means of selecting one of the two priority queues, `pq[pqi]`, with another place in the code referencing the other one as `pq[1-pqi]`, and, based on another condition, the code flip-flops between the pair by executing `pqi=1-pqi;`. As far as what exactly it's doing, it's mostly incomprehensible to me, and it would take a significant amount of time to extract any sense out of this very convoluted code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik. pqi and 1-pqi are indexes so for both pq.

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote, so what exactly would be the point you're making?

Comment: For some (possibly valid?) reason, the author decided that the best way to replace one of the items in the queue is to copy every other node to the other queue and then start using it instead. That reason is probably that `priority_queue` doesn't have any kind of 'replace this node' functionality.

Comment: Classmate of yours? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862953/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-two-pq-here-in-this-code-and-why-do-we-empty-the (I've seen other posts with this rather distinctive code too in the past...)

Comment: @Shawn I saw it, But it has the same problem.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik OK.

Comment: @PhilM So, the reason here. One working as a waiting list and the other for doing comparison?

Comment: @Shawn It's a great coincidence. Thanks for sharing this link. It also has some answers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's not for me this code. I'm just trying to trace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look through the code, you'll see the following comment:

```
// replace the node
// by emptying one pq to the other one
// except the node to be replaced will be ignored
// and the new node will be pushed in instead
```

So, one queue is always in use, and the other is empty. At some point, it is possible that a node in the active queue needs to be replaced. `priority_queue` does not, it seems, have the ability to replace a node, so the author (in the rest of that block) empties out the active queue into the empty one, until it gets to the one it wants to replace. It removes that obsolete node, dumps the rest of the active queue into the other one, and then adds the new (replacement) node, and switches which one is active.

Comment: @ I got the idea. I really appreciate your answer.